# Ковертация Java в Kotlin : почему не работает получившийся код?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, конвертация

Я изучаю разработку под Android по книге "Head First. Программирование для Android", при этом пытаюсь все приведенные примеры на Java перевести в Kotlin.

В главе 7 "Модульная структура" рассматриваются фрагменты. В этой главе для работы с фрагментом приведен следующий код на Java:

```
public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    private long workoutId;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        View view = getView();
        if (view != null) {
            TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            Workout workout = Workout.workouts[(int) workoutId];
            title.setText(workout.getName());
            TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
            description.setText(workout.getDescription());
        }
    }

    public void setWorkout(long id) {
        this.workoutId = id;
    }
}
```

Этот код работает. Теперь я конвертирую его в Kotlin стандартными средствами Android Studio. Получается такой код:

```
class WorkoutDetailFragment : Fragment() {
    private var workoutId: Long = 0
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val view = view
        if (view != null) {
            val title = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textTitle)
            val workout = Workout.workouts[workoutId.toInt()]
            title.text = workout.name
            val description = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.textDescription) as TextView
            description.text = workout.description
        }
    }

    fun setWorkout(id: Long) {
        this.workoutId = id
    }
}
```

Но этот код не работает. При компиляции запуске приложения я получаю ошибку:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workout/com.example.workout.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
```

Собственно, вопроса 2:

1. Почему код, полученный из конвертации Java в Kotlin не работает?
2. Как изменить получившийся код, чтобы он стал рабочим?

**UPD**

Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        class="com.example.workout.WorkoutListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list_frag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        class="com.example.workout.WorkoutDetailFragment"
        android:id="@+id/detail_frag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Стектрейс:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.workout, PID: 18504
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workout/com.example.workout.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305)
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
                      at com.example.workout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
                      at com.example.workout.WorkoutListFragment.onCreateView(WorkoutListFragment.kt)
                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
                      at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4819)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305) 
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944) 
                      at com.example.workout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: в 6й строчке xml какая то ошибка

Comment: наверное атрибут `android:name` надо добавить

Comment: 6-я строчка xml содержит начало тега fragment: 

<fragment

При этом java-код до конвертации в этой строчке ошибку не выдает

Comment: Добавлять фрагменты через разметку - плохая идея. В вашем случае, думаю, баг вызван неспособностью андроидСДК при парсинге XML найти не Java-файл с классом. Т.е. вряд ли можно это починить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, котлин компилируется в тот же DEX-байткод, только с дополнительным мусором)

Comment: @san-smith, Вы поддержку котлина в проекте вообще-то включили? И покажите весь стектрейс ошибки.

Comment: Покажите код xml файла

Comment: @woesss Поддержка котлина включена (в проекте есть файлы на нём). Стектрейс смогу выложить только часов через 8 - после работы. Но если коротко - приложение падает на строке `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Comment: Думаю, вы для Kotlin кода отличное имя пакета используете, чем в разметке.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Имя пакета одно и то же. Конвертация производилась стандартными средствами Android Studio

Comment: @woesss Добавил код разметки и стектрейс

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему конвертер не смог выдать рабочий код не могу знать, наверное это задача не простая и предполагается, что Вы уже знакомы с Kotlin и легко поправите недоразумения.

Ошибка говорит что параметром `savedInstanceState` в `onCreateView` пришёл `null` - оно и не удивительно, ведь фрагмент создаётся впервые, а не из сохранённого состояния.
Но в Kotlin переменная не может принимать значение `null`, если она не объявлена явно как `Nullable`, иначе он бросает исключение.
В данном случае мы можем сказать что в курсе про возможный `null`, взять на себя ответственность за его проверку и пометить как `Nullable` этот параметр, для этого просто добавляем знак вопроса к его типу:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
```

P.S. Хотя всё логично - в Андроид фрэймворке этот параметр не помечен аннотацией `@Nullable` и конвертеру негде было взять эту информацию.

Comment: Да, это решение работает, благодарю.